# Probability of balls of colors in two urns

Tags: probability

In one urn A there is $2$ red balls and $3$ white balls. In another urn B there is $3$ red balls and $1$ white ball. $4$ balls are taken out and returned from urn A and $5$ balls from urn B.

I could find the probability that two red balls were taken out from the urn A and that four red balls were taken out from urn B.

However, my problem is this one:

How can I find the probability that from balls taken out from urn A and urn B, there were two colors?

Comment: What does "$4$ balls are taken out and returned from urn A and $5$ balls from urn B." mean?

Comment: @lulu In urn A you take one ball, see its color and return it (4 times). Same for urn B, just that it will be 5 times. Remember that they have different colors. I want to know: the probability that in this whole process I take out two different colors. At least one red and at least one white.

Comment: Ok...well, just take $A$.  The probability that I draw only Red balls is $\left(\frac 25\right)^4$.  The probability that I draw only Red from $B$ is $\left(\frac 34\right)^5$ .  The probability that I draw only Red from both is the product of the two.  Can you finish from here?

Comment: ah ok, so it is a classic problem, sum up all available substitutions then subtract those of one unique color .

Comment: @lulu The only way I have thought is doing each case separately, which is too long. In addition, I know how to calculate the probability that there is only red or that there is only white. However, don't know how to use it.

Comment: Look at what I wrote, and at what @Idle001 is saying.  For problems like these it is much easier to look at the "bad" case (here, "all Red or all Black" ).  Once you can do that then just note that $P(Good)=1-P(Bad)$.

Comment: @lulu Therefore I thought about calculating $1-P(AllRed) + (1-P(AllWhite))$, being $P(AllRed)$ what you mentioned in third comment. However, didn't work (i.e. process I described is wrong).

Comment: No...$P(Bad)=P(All\;Red)+P(All\;White)$ so $P(Good)= 1 - \left(P(All\;Red)+P(All\;White)\right)$

Comment: To see that your formula can't be correct, suppose you drew millions of balls from the urns.  Then, effectively, $P(All\;Red)=P(All\;White)=0$ so your formula would return $2$, which can't be a probability.  I strongly recommend testing formulas on extreme cases...great way to build intuition.

Answer (score 1):

Let's follow the approach outlined in the comments.  As is often the case, it is much easier to work with the complement.  Thus, we'll compute the probability of getting the same color on all $9$ draws...the answer we want will be $1$ minus this.

Of course the probability of getting the same color is the sum of the probabilities of getting all Red and all White.

The probability of getting all Red:  Well, the probability of drawing a single Red from $A$ is $\frac 25$ so getting all Red from $A$ has probability $\left(\frac 25\right)^4$.  Similarly the probability of getting all Red from $B$ is $\left(\frac 34\right)^5$   These are independent events so the probability that both happen is just the product of the probabilities, hence:  $$P(All\;Red)=\left(\frac 25\right)^4 \times \left(\frac 34\right)^5\sim .006075$$

A parallel computation shows that

$$P(All\;White)=\left(\frac 35\right)^4 \times \left(\frac 14\right)^5\sim .000127$$

Now the probability of getting all one color is the sum of these, hence $$P(One\;Color)=P(All\;Red)+P(All\;White)\sim .0062$$

Of course, the question called for the probability that this did not happen, so we have to subtract from $1$.  Thus the answer is $$P(Two\;Colors)=1-P(One\;Color)\sim .9938$$

Comment: At the end I tried to do what you did. However, the answer is $0.6435$. I don't know what more to try.

Comment: Well, that's clearly wrong...given the set up you described.  Try it!  Easy enough to do the experiment.  You are saying that about a third of the time you should get the same color $9$ times in a row.  I expect the problem was asking something different.  Can you edit the question to repeat the problem exactly as it was worded?

Comment: to be clear:  the way I read what you wrote is "find the probability that both colors are seen in the $9$ balls you select."  That's the problem I addressed.

Comment: That's how I addressed it too. The problem is that the problem isn't written in English. But I'm sure the data about the balls are right. After the given data about the balls in the urns it says: "Find the probability that from the balls taken out from urn A and also from urn B, there are balls from both colors." Maybe it's meant "two colors" each urn by itself... But I don't promise.

Comment: Oh!  That's different.  They are asking for the probability that TWO things happen.  They want the $A$ balls to be of different colors AND the $B$ balls of different color.  That's easily addressed using the numbers from my post.  Can you do it?

Comment: Now I tried again and it was meant for each urn by itself. At the end I got the answer correctly. I'm so so sorry for my misunderstanding and mistaken explanation!!!

Comment: No problem.  Glad it got sorted out.